# Merging multidimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to "append" a vector to matrix, eg

```
[1 2; & (5       [1 2 5;
3 4]     6) -->   3 4 6];
```

trying to emulate math script. I seemingly don't understand arrays and pointers in C because when I try to do that in C I with the following code

EDIT: Posted messed up code which was redundant. When using the function mmerge, the "problem" persists.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//void printMatrix(const int N, const int M, double A[N][M]);

void mmerge(const int N, const double A[N][N], const double b[N], double F[N][N])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            F[i][j] = A[i][j];
        }
        F[i][N] = b[i];
    }
}

// Prints a two-dimensional array as a matrix
void printMatrix(const int N, const int M, double A[N][M]){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
        printf("|");
        for(j=0; j<M; ++j){
            printf(" % 8.4f", A[i][j]);
            if(j != M-1) printf(",");
        }
        printf(" |\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() 
{
    const int N=2;
    double A[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    double b[2] = {5,6};
    double F[2][3];
    mmerge(2,A,b,F);
    printMatrix(2, 3, F);
    return 0;
}
```

I get

```
|   1.0000,   2.0000,   3.0000 |
|   4.0000,   6.0000,   0.0000 |
```

What happens and why is it not the expected result?

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output: `untitled2.c:41:5: warning: pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C [-Wpedantic]`  and is referencing this statement: `mmerge(2,A,b,F);`

Comment: Suggest taking a different approach: `malloc` an array of pointers to `double`   Then malloc each row in the matrix.  Then to add another column, `realloc` each row to be 1 entry longer, then assign the new value to the added entry in each row

Comment: note: arrays in C are indexed from 0 to the (number of entries in array, -1)  so this statement: `F[i][N+1] = b[i]; is accessing beyond the end of the row in the `F[i]` array.  Suggest: `F[i][N] = b[i];`

Comment: @user3629249 I know that there are many better ways to do this. It's just that I used Matlab to much in the last time and seemingly have problems with c indexing

Comment: Please note that Matlab and C are two different languages

Comment: @user3629249 Fixed it, it was only wrong in one of the occurences

Comment: @user3629249 of course they are

Comment: of course the problem persists.  The length of each row in the matrix has not been extended so the new data is overwriting the first entry in the next row (in C, matrix rows are in sequence in memory)

Comment: Thank you it should be F[N][N+1] of course! Now I feel stupid

Answer (score 1):

Forgot `N+1`

I want to "append" a vector to matrix, eg

```
[1 2; & (5       [1 2 5;
3 4]     6) -->   3 4 6];
```

trying to emulate math script. I seemingly don't understand arrays and pointers in C because when I try to do that in C I with the following code

EDIT: Posted messed up code which was redundant. When using the function mmerge, the "problem" persists.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//void printMatrix(const int N, const int M, double A[N][M]);

void mmerge(const int N, const double A[N][N], const double b[N], double F[N][N]+1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            F[i][j] = A[i][j];
        }
        F[i][N] = b[i];
    }
}

// Prints a two-dimensional array as a matrix
void printMatrix(const int N, const int M, double A[N][M]){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
        printf("|");
        for(j=0; j<M; ++j){
            printf(" % 8.4f", A[i][j]);
            if(j != M-1) printf(",");
        }
        printf(" |\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() 
{
    const int N=2;
    double A[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    double b[2] = {5,6};
    double F[2][3];
    mmerge(2,A,b,F);
    printMatrix(2, 3, F);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your function after double F[2][3]; do?

Also, your merging function should be like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        F[i][j] = A[i][j];
    }
```

}

```
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        F[j][M-1] = b[j];
    }
```

Comment: just type this after the double F[2][3]; and print the answer.

Comment: The function expands every row vector with another element from the argument b. Your code does not work since the constants M is not defined. Also, A is a square matrix

Comment: try to put it in your merge function

Answer (score 0):

/*Bro your code is wrong here*/

void mmerge(const int N, const double A[N][N], const double b[N], double F[N][N]+1)

use double F[N][N+1]) instead of double F[N][N]+1).

[Corrected code with correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uKPm.png)